# Jenkins Slave Nodes Won't Start

Tags: jenkins, nodes, disconnect, slave

I have a simple Jenkins job set up and for some reason certain computers in the office are having trouble connecting as slave nodes.

-One computer connects fine, no issues.

-One connects using java web start then immediately disconnects

-One tries to run using java web start and is taken to the java download page even after re-installing java.

Comment: What kinds of slave machines are these? Linux? Windows? What version of Jenkins are you using? The one that connects fine - is that also using JNLP, or are you using SSH there? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: There could be many reasons. One of the reasons when it connects and immediately disconnects is if we give wrong `Remote FS root` in the slave configuration. Majority of the reasons lie in the configuration itself